# Show $\lim\limits_{\lambda\to\infty} e^{\lambda e^{\frac{t}{\sqrt{\lambda}}} - t\sqrt{\lambda} - \lambda} = e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}$.

Tags: taylor-expansion, normal-distribution, poisson-distribution

Show $\lim\limits_{\lambda\to\infty} e^{\lambda e^{\frac{t}{\sqrt{\lambda}}} - t\sqrt{\lambda} - \lambda} = e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}$.

In this case the underlying distribution is a Poisson Distribution with parameter $\lambda$.

Hint: Use Poisson Expansion.

Answer: Using the Taylor Series of $e^x$, I obtain:

$e^{\lambda e^{\frac{t}{\sqrt{\lambda}}} - t\sqrt{\lambda} - \lambda} = \sum\limits_{x = 0}^{\infty} \frac{\Big(\lambda e^{\frac{t}{\sqrt{\lambda}}} - t\sqrt{\lambda} - \lambda\Big)^x}{x!}$

However, I have no idea where to proceed from here.

Comment: What is "Poisson expansion"?

Comment: What I have been told is it is simply using the Taylor series expansion of $e^x$.

Comment: You wrote *"Hint: Use Poisson Expansion"* in your question.  Is "Poisson expansion" supposed to be "Taylor expansion"?

Comment: This is how the question was posed: "Poisson Expansion".

Comment: That's very strange.  I suspect that they really do mean Taylor expansion, and that you should expand the inner-$e^x$ rather than the outer-$e^x$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
 - t\sqrt{\lambda} - \lambda + \lambda e^{\frac{t}{\sqrt{\lambda}}}= 
- t \lambda^{1/2} - \lambda  + \lambda\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{t}{\lambda^{n/2}n!}\\
= \frac{t^2}{2!} + \frac{t^3}{\lambda^{1/2}3!} + \frac{t^4}{\lambda^{2/2}4!} + \cdots
$$
It follows that $\lim_{\lambda \to \infty} {\lambda e^{\frac{t}{\sqrt{\lambda}}} - t\sqrt{\lambda} - \lambda} = \frac{t^2}{2}$.

Because the function $e^x$ is continuous, we can conclude that 
$\lim_{\lambda \to \infty} e^{\lambda e^{\frac{t}{\sqrt{\lambda}}} - t\sqrt{\lambda} - \lambda} = e^{t^2/2}$, which is what we wanted.